KeyError at / 118 in django deployment
I have created a workflow for my repository and everything even the deployment is going fine and i have created the model in same environment as in the docker and workflow is running but still i am getting this:
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://mysite-olvdmbamqa-el.a.run.app/

Django Version: 4.0.2
Python Version: 3.11.5
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'welcome_deck',
 'movie_recommender',
 'irisapp']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 167, in _get_response
    callback, callback_args, callback_kwargs = self.resolve_request(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 290, in resolve_request
    resolver_match = resolver.resolve(request.path_info)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 592, in resolve
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 634, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 627, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1204, in _gcd_import
    <source code not available>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1176, in _find_and_load
    <source code not available>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1147, in _find_and_load_unlocked
    <source code not available>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 690, in _load_unlocked
    <source code not available>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 940, in exec_module
    <source code not available>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
    <source code not available>
  File "/app/mysite/urls.py", line 25, in <module>
    path('movie/',include('movie_recommender.urls')),
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/urls/conf.py", line 34, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1204, in _gcd_import
    <source code not available>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1176, in _find_and_load
    <source code not available>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1147, in _find_and_load_unlocked
    <source code not available>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 690, in _load_unlocked
    <source code not available>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 940, in exec_module
    <source code not available>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
    <source code not available>
  File "/app/movie_recommender/urls.py", line 2, in <module>
    from . import views
  File "/app/movie_recommender/views.py", line 26, in <module>
    similarity = load(open(model_path,'rb'))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/joblib/numpy_pickle.py", line 648, in load
    obj = _unpickle(fobj)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/joblib/numpy_pickle.py", line 577, in _unpickle
    obj = unpickler.load()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/pickle.py", line 1213, in load
    dispatch[key[0]](self)

Exception Type: KeyError at /
Exception Value: 118


Please help me to fix the code. I am providing the views.py also :
from django.shortcuts import render
from joblib import load
import requests
import os
from django.conf import settings
from django.views.decorators.cache import never_cache


# Create your views here.
def home(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'movies_list': movies_list['title'].values})



def fetch_poster(movie_id):
    response=requests.get('https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/{}?api_key=fbb18fe9735d1a3e0ad1531398ed1b13'.format(movie_id))
    data=response.json()
    return 'https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/'+ data['poster_path']


movies_list_path = os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR, 'savedmodels/movies.joblib')
model_path = os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR, 'savedmodels/similarity.joblib')


movies_list =load(open(movies_list_path, 'rb'))
similarity = load(open(model_path,'rb'))

def recommend(movies_list, movie):
    movie_index = movies_list[movies_list['title'] == movie].index[0]
    distances = similarity[movie_index]
    movie_list = sorted(list(enumerate(distances)), reverse=True, key=lambda x: x[1])[1:7]
    recommended_movies = []
    recommended_movies_posters = []
    for i in movie_list:
        movie_id = movies_list.iloc[i[0]].id
        recommended_movies.append(movies_list.iloc[i[0]].title)
        # fetch poster from API
        recommended_movies_posters.append(fetch_poster(movie_id))
    return recommended_movies, recommended_movies_posters

@never_cache
def recommend_movies(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        selected_movie_name = request.POST['movie_name']
        names, posters = recommend(movies_list, selected_movie_name)
        return render(request, 'recommend.html', {'movie_data': zip(names, posters), 'movies_list': movies_list['title'].values})

    return render(request, 'index.html', {'movies_list': movies_list['title'].values})

I have tried creating the model again in the environment and use git-lfs for the large file but still getting this error

can you please clarify what you are trying to do ?

I am creating a movie recommendation system and the model is similarity.joblib and i pushed it to the github action and it is perfectly deployed but when i check the webpage i found this is error and i am using google cloud platform

I see nothing wrong in your code, this is supposed to come when you are using different versions of joblib or changes in joblib file. any chance you are using git lfs ?

yes i am using git-lfs

can you once with git lfs pull and then try to run it

ok wait let me try

no it is still not working

I see, no idea brother after that.
